# System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DisplayName' because it is an empty string

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-managed-identity

I am working on a PowerShell script that needs to access Azure subscriptions of a particular tenant. The goal is for the script to retrieve info about the managed entities. The current errors I am facing are due to getting $subscriptions and using DisplayName as a parameter as seen in the screenshot below. What is the best way to get subscriptions info from a Tenant for managed identities?

```
param (
        [bool]$SendAllMessage = $true,
        [switch]$LocalDebug
    )
    
    #region Variables
    
    $azfNo = ""
    
    #endregion
    
    #region Connection to Azure
    $WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    
    $SecurityIssuesData = @()
    
    if ($LocalDebug) {
        $RunCommand = $LocalHelperLocation + "helper-Connect.ps1"
        $subscriptions = & $RunCommand -LocalDebug $LocalDebug
        $RunCommand = $LocalHelperLocation + "helper-waiver.ps1"
        $Waivers = & $RunCommand -azfNo $azfNo -LocalDebug $LocalDebug
    }
    else {
        $subscriptions = .\helper-Connect.ps1 -LocalDebug $LocalDebug
        $Waivers = .\helper-waiver.ps1 -azfNo $azfNo -LocalDebug $LocalDebug
    }
    #endregion
    
    $TenantIDs = $subscriptions | select TenantID | sort-object -Property TenantID -Unique
    $SubscriptionGuid = $subscriptions.Id
    
    foreach ($TenantID in $TenantIDs) {
    
        $TenantName = $subscriptions | select TenantName | where { $_.TenantID -eq $TenantID }
    
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-8.2.0
        $Resources = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $TenantName
         
        $ResourceType = "Managed Identities"
    
        ForEach ($Resource in $Resources) {
            
            $ResourceID = $SubscriptionGuid + "|" + $Resource.ResourceGroup + "|" + $Resource.DisplayName
            $ResourceName = $Resource.DisplayName
    
            # https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/src/Resources/Resources/help/Get-AzTag.md
            $AssetTags = Get-AzTag -ResourceId $ResourceID
    
            # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-8.2.0
            $SubscriptionTags = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $ResourceID
    
            $Status = "compliant"
            $Message = @()
    
            if ($LocalDebug) {
                $RunCommand = $LocalHelperLocation + "helper-GetAssetID.ps1"
                $ResourceAssetID = & $RunCommand -SubscriptionTags $null -ResourceGroupName $null -ResourceTags $Resource.Tags
            }
            else {
                $ResourceAssetID = .\helper-GetAssetID.ps1 -SubscriptionTags $null -ResourceGroupName $null -ResourceTags $Resource.Tags
            }
    
            #Region Logic
    
            # Identies must have a valid owner and AssetID tag and supported subscription tag.    
            if ($null -ne $ResourceAssetID -And $Resource.AppRole -contains "Owner" -And $AssetTags -ge 1 -And $SubscriptionTags -ge 1) {
                # Compliant
            }
            else {
                $Status = "noncompliant"
            }
    
            # End Logic
    
            $SecurityIssuesOther = [PSCustomObject]@{
                managedEntities = $Resource
            }
    
            $SecurityIssuesData += [PSCustomObject]@{
                Status           = $Status
                SubscriptionName = $null
                SubscriptionGuid = $null
                TenantID         = $TenantId
                TenantName       = $TenantName
                ResourceID       = $ResourceID
                ResourceGroup    = $null 
                ResourceType     = $ResourceType
                ResourceName     = $ResourceName
                AssetID          = $ResourceAssetID
                message          = $Message
                Other            = $SecurityIssuesOther
            }
    
        }
    }
    #region Send Message
    
    if ($LocalDebug) {
        $RunCommand = $LocalHelperLocation + "helper-sendmsg.ps1"
        & $RunCommand -azfNo $azfNo -SendAllMessage $SendAllMessage -TotalCompliant $TotalCompliant -TotalNoncompliant $TotalNoncompliant -TotalWaiver $TotalWaiver -SecurityIssues $SecurityIssuesData -SecurityIssuesSubscriptions $SecurityIssuesSubscriptions -LocalDebug $LocalDebug
    }
    else {
        .\helper-sendmsg.ps1 -azfNo $azfNo -SendAllMessage $SendAllMessage -TotalCompliant $TotalCompliant -TotalNoncompliant $TotalNoncompliant -TotalWaiver $TotalWaiver -SecurityIssues $SecurityIssuesData -SecurityIssuesSubscriptions $SecurityIssuesSubscriptions -LocalDebug $LocalDebug
    }
    #endregion
```

[image: Error Log]

Comment: the line producing the initial error is this one: `Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $TenantName`, as the message states, `$TenantName` is null and will always be null because of this line `$subscriptions | select TenantName | where { $_.TenantID -eq $TenantID }`. you're filtering the `$subscriptions` variable by their `TenantID` property however no such property can exist because you have only selected the `TenantName` property from that array: `select TenantName`.